# Azure -> Easy api in Node.js-> how to send android push notifications?

Tags: android, node.js, api, azure, push-notification

We are using azure easy API (node.js) for our mobile app. We have set up notification hubs already and have tested them - they all seem to be working. However, we are not sure how to invoke these notification hubs within the easy API - we have followed the entire documentation provided by Microsoft (e.g.: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-nodejs-how-to-use-notification-hubs/) and have tried out multiple things. 
Can someone point to examples / code snippets on how to send push notifications specifically from Easy API?

thanks
Sankar

Comment: You can refer to [How to use the Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your situation, you could follow the steps below to achieve your purpose.

1. Once your notification hub is set up, go to the Settings menu for
   your App Service and click on the Easy APIs option. Click on the +
   Add button and fill in the form.
   [image]
2. Click on the API and then click on Edit script. This will open Visual Studio Online. This will allow you to edit the script online.
   [image]
3. edit `notification.js` file with following content:

   ```
   var azure = require('azure-sb');
   module.exports = {
       "post": function (req, res, next) {        
           var hubname = 'yourhubname';
           var connectionstring = 'yourconnectingstring';
           var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService(hubname, connectionstring);
           var payload = {
              data: {
               message: 'Hello!'
             }
           };
           notificationHubService.gcm.send(null, payload, function(error) {
             if(!error) {
               res.status(200).send('succ');
             }
           });
       }
   };
   ```

   Note: Replace your own hubname and connectionstring above.
4. Install `azure-sb` module through Kudu. Go back to the Azure Portal, select your App Servcie, then Tools, followed by Kudu. Click on the PowerShell version of the Debug console.
   Change directory into site/wwwroot, then type the following into the console:

   `npm install –-save azure-sb`
5. test your easy API by Postman:
   [image]

   Eventually, your client device will receive the notification:

[image]

Help it helps. Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.